# How to pass two callback functions the same variables from an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to coding and currently working on the Wikipedia viewer project on FCC. I have two callback functions that rely on an AJAX request and use the same data, one to suggest searches as the user types into an input and one to display results when they hit enter.

For suggestions:

```js
function searchSuggest(data) {
  $('.suggestions').empty();

  var title = Array.from(data[1]);
  var url = Array.from(data[3]);
  var listLength = title.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    var listItem = `
      <li>
        <a href="${url[i]}" target="_blank">${title[i]}</a>
      </li>
    `;
    $('.suggestions').append(listItem);
  }
}
```

And for results:

```js
function display(data) {
  $('.results').empty();
  $('.suggestions').empty();

  var title = Array.from(data[1]);
  var snippet = Array.from(data[2]);
  var url = Array.from(data[3]);
  var listLength = title.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    var result = `    
      <a href="${url[i]}" target="_blank">
        <li>
          <span>${title[i]}</span>
          <p>${snippet[i]}</p>
        </li>
      </a>
    `;
    $('.results').append(result);
  }
  $('.results').addClass('show');
}
```

The AJAX request returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m48Vy.png)

Is there a way to pass the variables into both functions without repeating myself? Tried creating an object variable to contain the arrays but that didn't work.

Full code is on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/grgbtchr/pen/zdjVNE).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please don't post images of text. we can't read them inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable/value to as many functions as you want:

```
ajax(query, function(data) {
  // maybe check keycode here?
  display(data);
  searchSuggest(data);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant that both functions use the same variables (title, url, snippet) which are created from the ajax data, and I have to declare them in both functions at the moment. Is there a way to create these variables outside of the functions to then use inside both?

Comment: I mean, you can make `searchSuggest` accept `title` and `url` as argument, and similarly you can make `display` accept `title`, `url` and `snippet` as argument, but I don't think this improves anything. Leave the task of extracting the required values from the data inside the function. I.e. what you have seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you are thinking.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLpLYL?editors=0010

```
var input = $('#input');
var response = null;
var dataGlobal = {};

function ajax(query) {//ajax now only takes one variable  
  var start = 2;

  if (query.length >= start) {
    if (response != null)
      response.abort();

    response = $.ajax({
      url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com///en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&limit=8&suggest&search=' + query,
      type: 'GET',
      data: {},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        dataGlobal = data;
        searchSuggest(dataGlobal);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I have created a dataGlobal variable, and only call the ajax request for searchSuggest.

I set the dataGlobal variable to the results of the ajax request, and then use those stored results to call display.

Hope this helps :)